# Java MySQL SSL connection with specified cert

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, jdbc, mariadb

I am trying to make a Java application which uses jdbc (Connector/J) to connect to a mariadb database using SSL encryption.
I already created a self signed certificate a configured the server to use it.
When I try to connect I get an exception because the certificate isn't trusted because it was self signed and not added to the Java trust store.
Because I want to modify the TrustStore or use a different one for my application I searched for a way to tell only jdbc which cert is trusted, and found "https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/using-tlsssl-with-mariadb-connectorj/ Provide Certificate directly"

When I now try to connect with:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/<database>?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&serverSslCert=/tmp/ssl/server-cert.pem", "<username>", "<password>");
```

I get this exception which I already got before not using the serverSslCert parameter again:

```
Exception in thread "main" 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 136 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 129 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:203)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4901)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at gymcash.server.mysql.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:22)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at gymcash.server.mysql.MySQL.connect(MySQL.java:48)
    at gymcash.server.mysql.MySQL.connect(MySQL.java:52)
    at gymcash.server.main.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1964)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:328)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:322)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1614)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:188)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:304)
    at 

sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:154)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:80)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled$X509TrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(ExportControlled.java:297)
    ... 31 more
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong because the file exists, the path is absolute, and is the same used by the server. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I am using Java 8, mysql-connector-java-5.1.45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. One put your self signed cert or the certificate authority you used to sign your cert into the default java key store used by the JVM you are using to connect with. You need to use the Keytool to do that. But unless your managing an enterprise VM package you probably dont want to hijack the default keystore in the security package.

First you need to understand how the key tool works.

[Java Key tool commands][1]https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html

The problem is you may not have access to the default key store and it may not accept the certificate format your using. Requiring some gym work converting certificates and trying to match supported crypto algos.

Generally unless your managing an enterprise its better to just

1. generate a new keystore file
2. import your cert into this keystore ( or the certificate chain )
3. make sure you mark it as trusted
4. pass the keystore to your program at run time using the -D option.

I usually just add this to my code and set the properties before connecting to the DB

```
if (DB_SSL || SSL) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", KEYSTORE);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASS);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", KEYSTORE);
            System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", KEYSTORE_PASS);
        if (DEBUG_OPTION) {
            System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "true");
        }
    }

private static String KEYSTORE = "/home/me/.keystore";
private static String KEYSTORE_PASS = "changeit";
```

Comment: This is more or less the exact thing I didn't want to do. Because when I do this, than I override (for this programm) the trustStore and can't connect to servers I don't know the ca. I need a way to merge the default trustStore and self signed ca without changing the default trustStore or external programms.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly but I'm fairly sure the VM still loads the default truststore in jre/lib/security with all the standard root ca certs in it regardless. The lazzy way is just add your self signing ca here then any thing you sign until the next VM update will be trusted. Otherwise you role your own using the run time prams. You can even package your own keystore and trust store.

Comment: Ok I thought this will override the current default trust store, but I will try it by time

Comment: Thank you, It works now. I misunderstood how this property works.